# How to solve "The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip' does not exist."

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have imported a project into android studio 3.5 and I am getting this error when syncing with Gradle files

The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip' does not exist

Answer (score 0):

you can download this `gradle-4.10.1-all.zip` or you can add downloded gradel into

```
gradel-wrapper.properties

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

Comment: or you can see downloded .zip file in your privious projects gradel-wrapper.properties